# Plotting FFT in Python digitized data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, dft

I am measuring a voltage and sampling this.
From the measured data I want to do a FFT to get more information about the harmonics in the voltage. However, the results baffle me ...
Is the sampling frequency I have to choose here the same sample frequency with which I am sampling my voltage (and the same for the samplepoints)?
I attached a sample data set. It should be a sine wave with a frequency of 1 kHz.
link to data : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdv6uiy3lkeoomk/data.mat?dl=0

The code looks as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as fourier_plot
import scipy.fftpack as fft

# Number of samplepoints
N = 16384
# sample spacing
fs = 125e6/8
T = 1.0 /fs
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = data
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N/2)


fourier_plot.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]))
fourier_plot.show()
```

Comment: Is there any influence on the number of points or that it is not eaxactly one period?

Comment: did you confirm the input matlab data is correctly read in by the python ... I suggest you simply plot the sin curve data in python to check before trying to do the FFT